# My CSS is overwritten by Bootstrap in a React project

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I've been playing around in React to build a very simple project. Previously, I built my app with my own CSS files and decided to bring bootstrap into the project to see how I can leverage the two. I'm glad I did because I'm facing a small hang-up. The majority of my CSS renders with my components but, rather annoyingly, one background color is being overwritten. For sake of understanding why I figured I would try to figure it out. The best solution I could come up with was to leverage the cascading functionality of CSS by entering my CSS links after the link for bootstrap (within the `<head>` of `index.html`) like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/App.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/components/Reservations/Reservations.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/components/ReservationForm/ReservationForm.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/components/Card/Card.css" />
<title>React App</title>
```

This hasn't had the effect I was looking for, as my background color is still not rendering on the screen. As you might've seen, my CSS files for each component are located next to the corresponding `.jsx` file in my file tree. Perhaps I should have one CSS directory? What are your thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: proberly due to specificity weight then. With the informations you provided I see no reason why bootstrap should overwrite your css.

Comment: If you inspect the element that you’re referring to, choose the “computed” tab in the dev tools. Look at the background-color property and it should display what rule is affecting it. That may help you to identify the problem if it’s a specificity problem.

Comment: Thanks, @tacoshy, and @Jeff! You both got me headed in the right direction. In my jsx I gave my component of card a className of 'card'. It turns out `.card` is a keyword in bootstrap. Once I changed the className to 'reservation-card' I got what I was looking for. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As @Khadim Rana said, you can use `!important` after your css rule, eg.:

```css
.my-awesome-class {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

but it's not the most recommanded solution.
The "best practice" is to precise your css selector to be more precise than the bootstrap's one:

```css
.my-component-class .my-awesome-class {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the !important mention on your CSS line.
like
App.css

```css
div {
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: While this might technically solve the issue, it's generally a terrible idea to "just add !important". (In fact, people adding `!important` is often the cause of these sorts of issues)